# Android Studio, Unable to found item, when open file after download it

Tags: android

In Android Studio, I am getting two different errors, first: "Unable to found item", and then: "Access denied". This is happening when I open a file after downloading it. I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The files are being downloaded, but I cannot read them.
Below is my code:

```
//first error by this way
//String PATH = "/data/data/com.myproj.myproj/attafiles/";
//File folder = new File(PATH);
//            if (!folder.exists()) {
//                folder.mkdirs();
//            }
//URL url = new URL(imageURL);
//File file = new File(folder , fileName);

//Second error
URL url = new URL(imageURL);
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);

URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);


ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
      baf.append((byte) current);
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(baf.toByteArray());fos.close();
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
String fileExtension= MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path.toString());
String mimeType= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have both permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you already have both, try to refresh the filepath after download it.
Add this method to your class or your Util package:

```
public static void updateFile(Context context, String Newpath) {
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri
            .parse("file://" + Newpath)));
    Log.v(TAG, "[updateGallery] Updating gallery");
}
```

In other way, try to use the next method to read your file:

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("fileURL");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I modify the answer, try with the new method that I added

Comment: still problem, I think it is not allow to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW in private mode, and I don't need to store in external?